# Visual Studio Issue With Typing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So this issue probably has a really easy answer but I can not find it at all! I've been googleing for about 2 hours now and I've asked friends and so on but here it is.

---

### ISSUE

When I start typing code into c# and I want to make a space before the line it erases that part and puts the character I inserted in instead.

For example: http://gyazo.com/62b263de00ef141f0b57a72e4c92fb48

Im sorry for my bad English it is not my main language.

Comment: Seems like you have Insert on

Comment: Im wondering how to remove that feature.

Comment: It's the same for every single editor since.. probably MS-DOS times. Just press "Insert" on your keyboard to trigger modes between "Insert" and "Overwrite".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Err... maybe you have the override-mode activated by pressing the <kbd>Ins</kbd>-button?

Visual Studio will indicate the mode you're in at the bottom right corner as well.

[image]

### Edit:

As stated in the comments, the <kbd>Ins</kbd>-button might not be have the caption **Ins** on your keyboard, if you don't use the QWERTY layout. In this case you can also simply **double click** on the text in the bottom right corner to change your edit-mode as well.

(This was tested on Visual Studio 2013 Professional Update 5).

Comment: Best option, as it deals with multilingual keyboards. A lot of people are just saying hit the insert button, but what is that on their keyboard? They are not necessarily on the QWERTY system. At least with a screenshot, they have a chance of seeing physically where things are within their window and can attempt to change it.

Comment: Actually, I've got a **german** keyboard over here and it took me a second to think about what the buttons caption would be on the QWERTY-layout. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You have to press the <kbd>Ins</kbd> button.